# Multiplicar id con triggers

Tags: sql

Estoy intentando multiplicar el ID con un trigger, pero me devuelve el mismo resultado.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS incrementID //
CREATE TRIGGER incrementID BEFORE UPDATE ON fine 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE OLD.id SET NEW.id = OLD.id * 1000;
END//
```

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien el `UPDATE` que planteas. Prueba de esta manera a ver que tal.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS incrementID //
CREATE TRIGGER incrementID BEFORE UPDATE ON fine 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE fine SET id = NEW.id * 1000 WHERE id = OLD.id;
END//
```